# How to list Row Headers from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been trying to find a way to create Row Headers (DataGridView) from Tables.
My Table consists name of days e.g. Mon, Tue, Wed, ... so on.

How can I achieve this?
Sorry, I'm very new to C# and I need a huge help.

Here's my code:

```
        string queryString2 = "select * from DayType";
        using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = queryString2;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = (reader["WhichDay"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();


//UPDATE:
//This is what i'm trying to achieve:
//-------------------------------------------
//        | 12:00 | 13:00 | 14:00 | 15:00   ---> Read from SQL Table 2
//-------------------------------------------
//  Mon   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   
//-------------------------------------------
//  Tue   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0
//-------------------------------------------
//  Wed   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0
//-------------------------------------------
//  Thu   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0
//-------------------------------------------
//   |
//   V
//Read from SQL Table 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is your problem ?

Comment: I know it's a bit hard to explain. Let me try to explain it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
dataGridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = (reader["WhichDay"].ToString());
```

Comment: I'm using VS2013 Express now and I can't find dataGridView1.HeaderRow.

Comment: not sure how to help you mate, I have been using the same code, works for me, I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate, .net 4.0